# Generate large array of Hexadecimal numbers of size more that 8 MB

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to generate a large array of hexadecimal numbers and numbers are randomly generated. The size of the array ranges from 8 Mb to 40 Mb. I should implement it in C. I know I should use malloc for creating a large array, but couldn't figure out how to generate random hexadecimal numbers and put it in an array. Another constraint is that before every hexadecimal number there should be a "0x". If I use this

```
  str[i] = hex_digits[ ( rand() % 16 ) ];
```

I could generate a hexadecimal number but it doesn't have 0x in front of it. And I don't know how to use that with the pointer. I am not good in programming. Can anyone please guide me with this..!!

To make it clear, I am giving this array as input in AES implementation in C. In the code which I have, there is 10 hexadecimal numbers as input, but I have to try it with large inputs like 8 MB, 16 MB, 32 MB and 64 MB.

I tried to do some code and started implementing on simple array. The code is following:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   void main()
   {
     char a[10];
     int i,j,k;
     for(i=0;i<2;i++)
     {
       j=4*i;
       printf("%d\n",i);
       printf("%d\n",j);
       {
         a[j]='0';
         a[j+1]='x';
         a[j+2]='a';
         a[j+3]='2';
       }
     }
      for(k=0;k<8;k++)
       {
        printf("%s\n",&a[k]);
       }
     }
```

I thought if it works i can make it to large array. I am trying to put "0xa2" twice in the array, instead I am getting the following output.

0xa20xa2
xa20xa2
a20xa2
0xa2
xa2
a2
2

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Raghu.

Comment: some random number generation solutions here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16344/152

Comment: "0x" implies a **string** representation of a integer using hexadecimal characters.  Typically a "large array of hexadecimal numbers" would be a "large array of `int`" or "large array of `uint8_t`".  The post implies an fuzzy understanding of the underlying issues.  Suggest showing some code that you have done and we can work from there.

Comment: @chux I tried do some code and added it to the question, but I am not getting the desired output. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create random number in the usual fashion.  When printing, pre-pend the "0x".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void RandPrint(size_t n) {
  unsigned char *BigArray = malloc(n);
  if (BigArray != NULL) {

    // Add this line to vary the random numbers generated.
    // This is a simple method, better ones exist.
    srand(time());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      BigArray[i] = rand();
    }

    // If code needs to output the numbers, then print 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      printf("0x%02X ", BigArray[i]);
    }

    // If code needs to call an AES encryption routine
    AES_encryption(BigArray, n);
    // Not clear on what OP wants to do after encryption.

    free(BigArray);
  }
}

//Examples
RandPrint(10);
RandPrint(8L*1024*1024);
```

---

Suggest that the "0x" certainly does not need to be saved in the array nor the conversion of an integer to hexadecimal characters.  That is typically used for direct human reading or for textually saving/passing data in a human readable format.

Comment: This makes sense, but I have to give this as input to a program(aes for encryption). I am printing so that I can know whether it is correct or not.

Comment: @user3258621  Not clear on how your AES encryption program accepts data.  If it takes in in `stdin` like "0xa20 0xa2 ..." use `This_Program | AES_Encryption_Program`.  If the AES encryption program accepts binary data use `This_Program | AES_Encryption_Program` again, but change to `printf("%c", BigArray[i]);`.  Need more info on your AES encryption program to proceed.

Comment: Can I attach the program anywhere here?

Comment: @user3258621 aka raghu, Rather than attach the program, which may not run on my machine, simple post how data is sent to it.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/35YpGq4mNDpNMj7DJVQCZqv
just in case you want to check the code,click the link.
unsigned char temp2[32]= {0x00  ,0x11  ,0x22  ,0x33  ,0x44  ,0x55  ,0x66  ,0x77  ,0x88  ,0x99  ,0xaa  ,0xbb  ,0xcc  ,0xdd  ,0xee  ,0xff};
this the variable where the input is given

Comment: @raghu Looks like you need to use `BigArray` rather than `in` (from the linked code) and adjust other buffer sizes.  Good luck!